# Generate required field in WADL

Tags: java, web-services

I need to generate a WADL that have some attributes. To generate a WSDl with required=true, on top of my attribute i make this.

```
@XmlElement(name = "something", required = true)  
    public String getSomething() {  
         return something;  
    }
```

For Wadl, what will be the process? I don´t want to use @NotNull in my Web Service.